# Specific drawings with arrows and vertices in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I would like to know how I can create the drawings from page 7:

[image]

and page 9 from the following [article](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ulrik%20brandes%20left%20right%20pdf&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2F130.203.133.150%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Bjsessionid%3DCDEEDC64A5EAB38070F0C190B17772E6%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.217.9208%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=dk3iUY3XCsjcOaSjgNgP&usg=AFQjCNHa1G1QWwYeYajnuJtaQosfVxENMw&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZWU&cad=rja):

[image]

Comment: Have you asked the autor of the article for the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Remarks

I used Ti*k*Z for this solution. I created a style for the vertex, to avoid retyping. The figures are shifted in x direction, rather than specifying shifted coordinates. The bounding box needs to be adjusted by hand, because the control points of the bezier curves exceed the limits of the visible drawing.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    vertex/.style = {
        circle,
        fill=black,
        outer sep=2pt,
        inner sep=1pt
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    % We need to adjust the bounding box manually
    % as the control points enlarge it.
    \path[use as bounding box] (-1.5,-0.5) rectangle (10.5,5);

    \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
        \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
        \node[below] at (o) {root};
        \draw node[vertex] (a) at (0,3) {};
        \draw node[vertex] (b) at (0,4) {};
        \node[above] at (b) {$v$};

        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (a) (a) -- (b);
        \draw[blue,->] (b) .. controls (-1,4.5) .. node[below right] {$e_1$} (0,2);
        \draw[blue,->] (b) .. controls (1,4.5) and (-3,7) .. node[below right] {$e_2$} (0,1);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
        \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
        \node[below] at (o) {root};
        \draw node[vertex] (a) at (0,3) {};
        \draw node[vertex] (b) at (0,4) {};
        \node[above] at (b) {$v$};

        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (a) (a) -- (b);
        \draw[blue,->] (b) .. controls (-1,4.5) .. node[below right] {$e_1$} (0,1);
        \draw[red,->] (b) .. controls (1,4.5) .. node[below left] {$e_2$} (0,2);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
        \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
        \node[below] at (o) {root};
        \draw node[vertex] (a) at (0,3) {};
        \draw node[vertex] (b) at (0,4) {};
        \node[above] at (b) {$v$};

        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (a) (a) -- (b);
        \draw[blue,->] (b) .. controls (-1,4.5) .. node[below right] {$e_1$} (0,2);
        \draw[red,->] (b) .. controls (1,4.5) .. node[below left] {$e_2$} (0,1);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
        \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
        \node[below] at (o) {root};
        \draw node[vertex] (a) at (0,3) {};
        \draw node[vertex] (b) at (0,4) {};
        \node[above] at (b) {$v$};

        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (a) (a) -- (b);
        \draw[red,->] (b) .. controls (1,4.5) .. node[below left] {$e_1$} (0,2);
        \draw[red,->] (b) .. controls (-1,4.5) and (3,7) .. node[below left] {$e_2$} (0,1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    % We need to adjust the bounding box manually
    % as the control points enlarge it.
    \path[use as bounding box] (-1,-0.5) rectangle (1.5,5.5);

    \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
    \node[below] at (o) {root};
    \draw node[vertex] (a) at (0,1) {};
    \draw node[vertex] (b) at (0,2) {};
    \draw node[vertex] (c) at (0,3) {};
    \draw node[vertex] (d) at (0,4) {};
    \node[above] at (d) {$v$};

    \draw (d) node[left] {$e_1$} -- (-0.5,4.5);
    \filldraw[draw=blue,fill=blue!50]
        (-0.5,4.5) .. controls (-1,5) and (-0.75,4.5) .. ($(c)+(180:4pt)$)
        arc[start angle=180, end angle=270, radius=4pt]
        -- ($(b)+(90:4pt)$) .. controls (-1,5) .. (-0.5,4.5);
    \draw (d) node[right] {$e_2$} -- (0.5,4.5);
    \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!50]
        (0.5,4.5) .. controls (1,5) and (0.75,4.5) .. ($(c)+(0:4pt)$)
        arc[start angle=0, end angle=-90, radius=4pt]
        -- ($(b)+(90:4pt)$) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=4pt]
        ($(b)+(0:4pt)$) .. controls (1,5) .. (0.5,4.5);
    \draw[red,thick,->] (0.5,4.5) .. controls (1,5) .. ($(b)+(0:4pt)$);
    \draw[->] (-0.5,4.5) .. controls (-1,5) and (3,7) .. (a);

    \draw[->] (o) -- (a) (a) -- (b) (b) -- (c) (c) -- node[left] {$e$} (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image] [image]

Comment: Wow! Amazing! Thank you so much! :-)